# Django all-auth app, how to modify /account/profile page to display custom view

Tags: django, django-allauth

After setting up the All-Auth app, when user logs in, he gets redirected to: `accounts/profile/` page which tells us that the view doesn't exist.

I'm trying to figure out what kind of thing to include there, and decided to allow the user to change their basic information.

I have a `users` app with a `Teacher` model, which is set up as follows:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    rate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want the `accounts/profile/` page to show a form, containing this information. The user can edit these fields and also edit their Firstname, Lastname and Email, which belong to a different Model - `User`.

I can't seem to get started on this. When I created a detailed view for the profile page, I get an error saying:

> No PK or SLUG provided

I want Django to change the current users info, not based on the primary key in the URL. Do I need a custom view? I've looked at [other solutions[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724344/how-can-i-display-a-user-profile-using-django)
but they seem to be utilising the private key parameter.

What I need is a working view function, something similar to (**not working**):

```
def get_teacher_info(request):
    current_user = request.user
    teacher = get_object_or_404(Teacher, username=current_user.username)
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', {
            'user':current_user,
            'teacher': teacher,
            'error_message': "The field is blank",
        })
```

and in the `accounts/urls.py` I've added:

```
url(r"^profile/$", views.get_teacher_info, name="account_profile"),
```

but when I make calls like `{% teacher.rate %}` in the html template, I get:
Invalid block tag on line 5: 'teacher.rate'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Did you set: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS & ACCOUNT_ADAPTER in settings.py?

Comment: And also please try: url(r"^profile/$", views.get_teacher_info, name="get_teacher_info"),

Comment: I've not set the above, but I basically lifted the code from the default 'polls' app. And it works there without setting those variables. I tried the 2nd comment too, without success

Comment: try to define function get_absolute_url to return slug or PK or username on your model

Answer (score 0):

The def get_teacher_info(request) function and the urls.py entry are working.  Looks like the issue may be in the template.  Use {{ instead of {% tags.  So use {{ teacher.rate }} not {% teacher.rate %} in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to `/accounts/profile/` After the login is the default behavior of Django. `django-allauth` is using the same default behavior from Django settings.

Now if you want to modify this default redirect url then change it to

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/custom/redirect-url'`

**Important Note:** Without a starting `/` you're redirecting to a path that is appended to the CURRENT URL. You need to use a leading slash to redirect to a path that is appended to the domain root. [further details on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772001/redirect-after-login-simply-appends-login-redirect-url). In short, without a starting `/` you will end up with

`../login/callback/custom.redirect-url` (appended to current url)